# what should I do if program gived me "} expected" error in c#?

Tags: c#

can you help me with this c# code? I made kinda simple quiz game with 6 questions. It gives me "} expected" error, but I checked it twice and can't find the mistake. I don't understand what is a problem here. Ngl, tried to run it 10 times or more and correct some places, but it still gives this error. What should I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OlkeQuiz
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {

        // quiz game variables

        int correctAnswer;
        int questionNumber = 1;
        int score;
        int percentage;
        int totalQuestions;

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            askQuestion(questionNumber);

            totalQuestions = 6;
        }

        private void checkAnswerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var senderObject = (Button)sender;

            int buttonTag = Convert.ToInt32(senderObject.Tag);

            if (buttonTag == correctAnswer)
            {
                score++;
            }

            if (questionNumber == totalQuestions)
            {
                // work out the percentage

                percentage = (int)Math.Round((double)(score * 100) / totalQuestions);

                MessageBox.Show(
                   "Тест аяқталды" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Сіз " + score + " сұраққа дұрыс жауап бердіңіз. " + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Сіздің жалпы пайызыңыз " + percentage + "%" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Қайтадан ойнау үшін ОК батырмасын басыңыз" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Ойынды өткеніңіз үшін алғыс айтамыз!"
                   );
                score = 0;
                questionNumber = 0;
                askQuestion(questionNumber);

            }

            questionNumber++;
            askQuestion(questionNumber);

        private void askQuestion(int qnum)
        {

            switch(qnum)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.мухтар_ауезов;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "1.Алматыда ашылған алғашқы театр қалай аталады?";

                    button1.Text = "Алатау-дәстүрлі өнер театры";
                    button2.Text = "Республикалық неміс драма театры";
                    button3.Text = "М.Әуезов атындағы драма театры";
                    button4.Text = "Ғ.Мүсірепов атындағы ТЮЗ";

                    correctAnswer = 4;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ғабит_мүсірепов;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "2.Ғ.Мүсірепов атындағы ТЮЗда өткізілген алғашқы пъеса қалай аталады?";

                    button1.Text = "Алтын кілт";
                    button2.Text = "Құлагер";
                    button3.Text = "Қызыл телпек";
                    button4.Text = "Бір түп алма ағашы";

                    correctAnswer = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.артишок;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "3.Алғашкы тәуелсіз театр компаниясы қалай аталады?";

                    button1.Text = "АРТиШОК";
                    button2.Text = "Бата";
                    button3.Text = "Interius";
                    button4.Text = "Kelt";

                    correctAnswer = 2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.лермонтов;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "4.М.Ю.Лермонтов атындағы мемлекеттік академиялық орыс драма театры Алматыда кай спектаклімен ашылды?";

                    button1.Text = "Біздің қаланың жігіті";
                    button2.Text = "Две зимы и три лета";
                    button3.Text = "Шапқыншылық";
                    button4.Text = "Страх";

                    correctAnswer = 3;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.абай;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "5.Абай атындағы қазақ мемлекеттік академиялық опера және балет театры қашан құрылды?";

                    button1.Text = "1963 жылы 31 тамыз";
                    button2.Text = "1943 жылы 18 наурыз";
                    button3.Text = "1934 жылы 13 қаңтар";
                    button4.Text = "1984 жылы 25 сәуір";

                    correctAnswer = 4;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.куклы;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "6.Мемлекеттік қуыршақ театрындағы қойылымдар қай тілде өткізіледі?";

                    button1.Text = "Орыс";
                    button2.Text = "Қазақ және орыс";
                    button3.Text = "Қазақ және ағылшын";
                    button4.Text = "Қазақ";

                    correctAnswer = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Count your `{`s and `}`s. They should always be matched.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1513 has a nice illustration for this Error.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be lacking a `}` just after:

```
        questionNumber++;
        askQuestion(questionNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error talks itself. You've just missed closing the function `checkAnswerEvent`. Try This:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OlkeQuiz
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {

        // quiz game variables

        int correctAnswer;
        int questionNumber = 1;
        int score;
        int percentage;
        int totalQuestions;

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            askQuestion(questionNumber);

            totalQuestions = 6;
        }

        private void checkAnswerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var senderObject = (Button)sender;

            int buttonTag = Convert.ToInt32(senderObject.Tag);

            if (buttonTag == correctAnswer)
            {
                score++;
            }

            if (questionNumber == totalQuestions)
            {
                // work out the percentage

                percentage = (int)Math.Round((double)(score * 100) / totalQuestions);

                MessageBox.Show(
                   "Тест аяқталды" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Сіз " + score + " сұраққа дұрыс жауап бердіңіз. " + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Сіздің жалпы пайызыңыз " + percentage + "%" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Қайтадан ойнау үшін ОК батырмасын басыңыз" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Ойынды өткеніңіз үшін алғыс айтамыз!"
                   );
                score = 0;
                questionNumber = 0;
                askQuestion(questionNumber);

            }

            questionNumber++;
            askQuestion(questionNumber);
        } // <--- MISSED THIS

        private void askQuestion(int qnum)
        {

            switch(qnum)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.мухтар_ауезов;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "1.Алматыда ашылған алғашқы театр қалай аталады?";

                    button1.Text = "Алатау-дәстүрлі өнер театры";
                    button2.Text = "Республикалық неміс драма театры";
                    button3.Text = "М.Әуезов атындағы драма театры";
                    button4.Text = "Ғ.Мүсірепов атындағы ТЮЗ";

                    correctAnswer = 4;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ғабит_мүсірепов;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "2.Ғ.Мүсірепов атындағы ТЮЗда өткізілген алғашқы пъеса қалай аталады?";

                    button1.Text = "Алтын кілт";
                    button2.Text = "Құлагер";
                    button3.Text = "Қызыл телпек";
                    button4.Text = "Бір түп алма ағашы";

                    correctAnswer = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.артишок;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "3.Алғашкы тәуелсіз театр компаниясы қалай аталады?";

                    button1.Text = "АРТиШОК";
                    button2.Text = "Бата";
                    button3.Text = "Interius";
                    button4.Text = "Kelt";

                    correctAnswer = 2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.лермонтов;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "4.М.Ю.Лермонтов атындағы мемлекеттік академиялық орыс драма театры Алматыда кай спектаклімен ашылды?";

                    button1.Text = "Біздің қаланың жігіті";
                    button2.Text = "Две зимы и три лета";
                    button3.Text = "Шапқыншылық";
                    button4.Text = "Страх";

                    correctAnswer = 3;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.абай;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "5.Абай атындағы қазақ мемлекеттік академиялық опера және балет театры қашан құрылды?";

                    button1.Text = "1963 жылы 31 тамыз";
                    button2.Text = "1943 жылы 18 наурыз";
                    button3.Text = "1934 жылы 13 қаңтар";
                    button4.Text = "1984 жылы 25 сәуір";

                    correctAnswer = 4;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.куклы;

                    lblQuestion.Text = "6.Мемлекеттік қуыршақ театрындағы қойылымдар қай тілде өткізіледі?";

                    button1.Text = "Орыс";
                    button2.Text = "Қазақ және орыс";
                    button3.Text = "Қазақ және ағылшын";
                    button4.Text = "Қазақ";

                    correctAnswer = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```